# WordPress - Using same file for home and archive

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We would like the home (home.php) and archive (archive.php) pages to look the same in our template.

Is it possible to use the same file by adding a code to functions.php or something like that? So that we don't have to keep both updated with the latest code.

Cheers

Comment: I think you can point the wordpress homepage to any URL on the site within the admin settings. Could you point the homepage to the archive URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code you want to have in your *archive.php* file, or the otherway around. Then in the opposite file you want to have as a duplicate, use the [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function to call the other template.

For example...

***archive.php***

```
<div>
    content etc
</div>
```

***home.php***

```
<?php get_template_part( 'archive' ); ?>
```